# Want to Remove words till first comma

Tags: php

Assume that i have a variable which contain 3  to 6 words.
But i want to remove words till first comma.

```
$str="Plot-23, Your Area, Your City";
```

Please help me how can i achieve it?

I want result like this.

```
$str="Your Area, Your City";
```

Comment: Is it a guarantee that there will be a comma in the input string? Are there cases where there will not be a comma? This is important because some solutions require at least one comma and some do not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
explode(",", $str, 2)[1];
```

`explode()` splits the string in to parts at a specified delimiter. In this case the delimiter is a comma. The 3rd parameter specifies a limit for the number of times to split the string. Specifying a limit of 2 means the string will only be split in to two parts, with one part being before the first comma and the other part after. The second part is then accessed using an array index.

If you are using PHP<5.4 you will need to assign the result of `explode()` to a temporary variable. Thanks @Don'tPanic for pointing this out.

```
$split = explode(",", $str, 2);
echo $split[1];
```

Comment: For "Plot-23, Your Area, Your City", this will return " Your-Area". I don't think that is the user wants.

Comment: @kainaw [Nope](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e65fcc5b6910536673e9d1c37ac8f5041a8d715f).

Comment: You are correct. I didn't pay attention to the third parameter. I suggest explaining what the third parameter is used for.

Comment: @kainaw Sure. Will do.

Comment: PHP version must be >= 5.4 to use direct array dereferencing like that. Hopefully everyone's PHP version is by now, but who knows.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Thanks for that useful information. I've added it to the answer.

Comment: Also, not sure if it matters to OP, but the returned string will have a space at the beginning unlike their desired result. (Sorry, not trying to be a pest.) If it does matter, ltrim on the result would probably work better than exploding on ", ", in case there isn't actually a space after the first comma.

Answer (score 2):

Note: After the question showed that the first comma was to be removed, I altered this answer to remove the first comma.

This removed everything up to the first comma, the first comma, and space after the comma.

```
$str = preg_replace('/^[^,]*,\s*/', '', $str);
```

/ ... / is a regular expression. The first ^ means "beginning of the string." The [^,] means "not a comma." The * means zero or more matching characters. The , is just a comma - what you are looking for. The \s is a space character.

Answer (score 2):

```
$str = substr($str, strpos($str, ',') + 1);
```